# How to close the timer in android?

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

Hi in my coding I need to create a timer task for execution some function this function called multiple times so before running the same task i need to cacel the old running task and start this timer again. I have used the `featuredCouponRotationTimer.cancel();` but it is not working, I'm getting some error in logcate

```
public void startPagerRotationTimer(){

    featuredCouponRotationTimer.cancel();
    featuredCouponRotationTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!isBeingTouched){
                ActivityMain.getActivityMain().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                     Log.i("pagerDurationFeaturedCoupons","setData :working");

                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }

    }, 0, 2000);
}
```

Logcat error

```
02-25 20:25:18.210      816-816/com.shoplylabs.shoplys E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled
            at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:561)
            at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:528)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.view.ViewContainerFeaturedCoupon.startPagerRotationTimer(ViewContainerFeaturedCoupon.java:190)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.view.ViewContainerFeaturedCoupon.setData(ViewContainerFeaturedCoupon.java:182)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.adapters.AdapterShoplyCouponStaggeredGrid.getView(AdapterShoplyCouponStaggeredGrid.java:156)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.components.staggeredgridview.StaggeredGridView.obtainView(StaggeredGridView.java:1533)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.components.staggeredgridview.StaggeredGridView.fillDown(StaggeredGridView.java:1245)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.components.staggeredgridview.StaggeredGridView.populate(StaggeredGridView.java:846)
            at com.shoplylabs.shoplys.components.staggeredgridview.StaggeredGridView.onLayout(StaggeredGridView.java:797)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2260)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2007)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographe
```

Please help me on this where i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clearly stated:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled

You need to re-initialize your `featuredCouponRotationTimer` object to avoid the `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: like featuredCouponRotationTimer = new Timer();  featuredCouponRotationTimer.cancel();

Comment: you can't use the `Timer` instance after canceling it, so you must re-init AFTER the `cancel()` call

Comment: can you give some example or can you say what line i must add on my coding

Comment: `featuredCouponRotationTimer.cancel();`
`featuredCouponRotationTimer = new Timer();`

Comment: i have tried it i'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: perform a null-check as suggested by *Nino Lenoska*

Comment: no this is not working 2 task is running at the same time first task is not getting cancel

Comment: always my featuredCouponRotationTimer is null so it is not canceling plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Timers are not recommended for new code, you should take a look at [ScheduledExecutorServices](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

If you want to keep Timers, use this :

```
public void startPagerRotationTimer()
{
    if (featuredCouponRotationTimer != null)
    {
        featuredCouponRotationTimer.cancel();
    }

    featuredCouponRotationTimer = new Timer();
    featuredCouponRotationTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (!isBeingTouched)
                    {
                        ActivityMain.getActivityMain().runOnUiThread(
                                new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {

                                        Log.i("pagerDurationFeaturedCoupons", "setData :working");
                                    }
                                }
                                                                    );
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 2000);
}
```

Comment: no this is not working 2 task is running at the same time first task is not getting cancel

Comment: This is the way to cancel **a** timer. You need to run this code for each Timer you start (and keep their references in an ArrayList<Timer>)

Comment: always my featuredCouponRotationTimer  is null so it is not canceling plz help me

Comment: I posted a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720180/terminating-timer-in-android/28722707#28722707), using ScheduledExecutorService and Singleton pattern. Based on your post and comments, I guess this is the best way to reformat your code.